Webscraping data is not encoded correctly in CSV
I'm using the below code to scrape a website and export the data to CSV. It works well except that the title and summary fields are not encoded correctly in the CSV. It's showing apostroshes as â€™ for instance.
I tried adding in the 'response.encoding' line but that didn't fix it. Not sure what else to do. In case it's relevant, I'm using Replit to run the code and Excel to open the CSV.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def scrape_report_content(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    content_div = soup.find('div', class_='usa-prose pep-prose margin-top-6')
    if content_div:
        # Extract all paragraphs inside the content_div
        paragraphs = content_div.find_all('p')
        content = '\n'.join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in paragraphs])
        return content.strip()
    else:
        return None

base_url = "https://oig.hhs.gov/reports-and-publications/all-reports-and-publications/"
page_limit = 50

report_data = []

for page in range(1, page_limit + 1):
    page_url = f"{base_url}?page={page}"
    print(f"Scraping page {page}...")

    # Fetch the page content
    response = requests.get(page_url)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    reports = soup.find_all("div", class_="usa-card__container")

    for report in reports:
        title_tag = report.find("a")
        title = title_tag.get_text(strip=True)
        link = "https://oig.hhs.gov" + title_tag['href']
        audit, agency, date = [e.get_text(strip=True) for e in report.find_all("dd")]

        content = scrape_report_content(link)

        report_data.append({
            "Title": title,
            "URL": link,
            "Report Number(s)": audit,
            "Agency": agency,
            "Date": date,
            "Content": content
        })

# Export to CSV
csv_file = "OIG_Reports.csv"
with open(csv_file, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    fieldnames = ["Title", "URL", "Report Number(s)", "Agency", "Date", "Content"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in report_data:
        writer.writerow(data)

print(f"Data exported to {csv_file}")


u can use pandas then pd.DataFrame(report_data).to_csv(csv_file)

I've fiddled with your script and used Pandas to export to CSV. This is generally a better approach than hand-crafting your CSV export because Pandas will "do the right thing".
It should not be necessary to explicitly set the encoding because the documents you're retrieving have <meta charset="utf-8"> in their <head>.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

PAGES = 50
URL_BASE = "https://oig.hhs.gov"
URL_PATH = "/reports-and-publications/all-reports-and-publications/"
CSV_FILE = "OIG_Reports.csv"

def scrape_report_content(url):
    print(f"- {url}")
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    content = soup.find('div', class_='usa-prose pep-prose margin-top-6')
    if content:
        paragraphs = content.find_all('p')
        content = '\n'.join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in paragraphs]).strip()
    
    return content

data = []

for page in range(1, PAGES + 1):
    page_url = f"{URL_BASE}{URL_PATH}?page={page}"
    print(f"Scraping page {page}...")

    response = requests.get(page_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    reports = soup.find_all("div", class_="usa-card__container")

    # Iterate over index pages, processing list of reports on each page.
    #
    for report in reports:
        link = report.find("a")
        audit, agency, date = [desc.get_text(strip=True) for desc in report.find_all("dd")]

        content = scrape_report_content(URL_BASE + link['href'])

        data.append({
            "title": link.get_text(strip=True),
            "url": link,
            "report_number": audit,
            "agency": agency,
            "date": date,
            "content": content
        })

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(CSV_FILE, index=False)

For repeatability, these are the packages that I'm using:
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
pandas==2.2.2
requests==2.32.3


Adding a BOM to the beginning of your CSV file can help Excel recognize it as UTF-8 encoded. Here's how you can modify the script to include a BOM:

with open(csv_file, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig')
as file

